# Access mysql db and server side scripts from local file

Tags: php, javascript, css, html, firefox-os

This is more general design kind of question. My major project is to create native app for Firefox OS. Which therefor means JavaScript, jQuery, HTML5 and css. This application should have several functions. But as a general design goes I need local html,css,js application running under firefox OS with ability to access server php scripts and mysql db, but because application is running on client side, I have a major problem with communication between application and server. Which technology, language, API or JS functions could I use for Login check, registration, messaging. How can I access server from local (on PC or Mobile Device) files. There is possibility that I'm missing some point or that my whole understanding of the problem is wrong, but is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apps are built using standard Web technologies with additional metadata that allows the User Agent to discover, install, launch, and grant them additional privileges.

So says [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/apps).

The usual way to interact with remote, shared databases is to place a RESTful HTTP front end in front of them and access that with JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

XHR, WebSocket or TCPSocket.

FYR:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets
- There is no TCPSocket document on MDN, but you can study gaia email app.

  - https://raw.github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/master/apps/email/js/ext/gaia-email-opt.js